# Google Maps Api: Polyline on "Editcomplete"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been using Google Maps Api for a while and I recently checked that there is new stuff: Drawing Manager. I was playing with this since two days ago and now I want to know something.  I'm looking for an Event fired when the Polyline is being edited.

There is a `polylinecomplete` event but it only works when you create a new Polyline on the map. But when I set the polyline editable `.setEditable(true)` it doesn't. I can't find a way to get a `draggend` event for the points on a Polyline or something like "changed_points".

[image]

Can you suggest something? I've tried all the events for the Polyline but without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found "capturing_changed" when I was checking all the properties of the polyline. I'm not sure if this the correct way of capturing the event but it works fine. It works when the markers on the line are dragged (start and end).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolyline, 'capturing_changed', function(e) {
     var path = this.getPath();
     // Path... blah blah
});
```